# How does the identity $b^{n}-a^{n} = (b-a)(b^{n-1} + b^{n-2}a + \cdots + a^{n-1})$ yield the inequality $b^{n}-a^{n} < (b-a)nb^{n-1}$?

Tags: inequality

I was reading Rudin's Principles of Mathematical Analysis and I wasn't sure how the identity $$b^{n}-a^{n} = (b-a)(b^{n-1} + b^{n-2}a + \cdots + a^{n-1})$$ yields the inequality $$b^{n}-a^{n} < (b-a)nb^{n-1}$$ when $0 <a<b$.

Comment: Because in the parentheses there are $n$ terms, all but one of which is strictly less than $b^{n-1}$ (and the other *is* $b^{n-1}$).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $0<a<b$, for $k>0$ we have that  $a^k<b^k$, then $b^{n-1-k}a^k<b^{n-1-k}b^k=b^{n-1}$. That means that each of your terms of the form $b^{n-1-k}a^k$ is less than $b^{n-1}$. Hence
\begin{align}&(b-a)(b^{n-1}+b^{n-2}a+b^{n-3}a^2+\dots a^{n-1})\\&<(b-a)(b^{n-1}+b^{n-1}+b^{n-1}+\dots b^{n-1})=(b-a)nb^{n-1}
\end{align}

Another way that I personally like (because I think is more natural) to see this inequality is by  using Fundamental theorem of calculus $f(b)-f(a)=\int_a^b f'(x) dx$ for $f(x)=x^n$, we get that 
$$b^{n}-a^n=\int_{a}^b nx^{n-1}dx<\int_{a}^bnb^{n-1}dx=(b-a)nb^{n-1}.$$

Answer (score 1):

$a < b$.

So if $a^k < b^k$.

So $b^{n-1} + b^{n-2}a + b^{n-3}a^2 + ...... + b^2a^{n-3} + ba^{n-2} + a^{n-1} <$

$b^{n-1} + b^{n-2}b + b^{n-3}b^2 + ...... + b^2b^{n-3} + bb^{n-2} + b^{n-1} =$

$b^{n-1} + b^{n-1} + b^{n-1} + ...... + b^{n-1}+ b^{n-1} + b^{n-1} = nb^{n-1}$

And $(b-a) > 0$ so

$(b-a)(b^{n-1} + b^{n-2}a + b^{n-3}a^2 + ...... + b^2a^{n-3} + ba^{n-2} + a^{n-}) <$

$(b-a)(b^{n-1} + b^{n-2}b + b^{n-3}b^2 + ...... + b^2b^{n-3} + bb^{n-2} + b^{n-1}) =$

$(b-a)(b^{n-1} + b^{n-1} + b^{n-1} + ...... + b^{n-1}+ b^{n-1} + b^{n-1}) = (a-b)nb^{n-1}$